# How to open two Banshee players at once

Tags: sound, rhythmbox, music, banshee, mp3

I want to play more .mp3 files at once, but Banshee/Rhythmbox players seems to allow only one file to be played at a time. I wanted to solve this by opening multiple Banshee players, but I can't get more than one to be up at a time. How can I solve this?

I can open both Banshee and Rhythmbox at the same time and play two files, but I'd like to be able to play as many files as I want to, so this solution isn't scalable.

Answer (score 0):

Start banshee two times from the command line with --disable-dbus option. It should work.